# Generate duplicate string on a line

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with hundreds of lines.  Here are 3 sample lines.

```
"A",
"B",
"C",
```

(The quote signs are actually there.)

I want to use a Linux utility to change the lines and duplicate the original string on each line.  For example:

```
FixedString1 A FixedString2 A
FixedString1 B FixedString2 B
FixedString1 C FixedString2 C
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the input CSV? If so, are the CSV format's special quoting rules applied to the values in the input (a field with value `"A",B` (embedded quotes and comma) would be encoded as `"""A"",B"` in CSV), and how would this look in the output (i.e., is the output CSV too?)

Comment: You've shown three input lines. In the output how does `"A"` map to `FixedString1 A FixedString2 A`? Are we being asked to invent `FixedString1` and `FixedString2`? What about changing the double-quoted `"A"` to just `A` and replacing the comma with a space?

Answer (score 2):

##### Like this

- with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/^"([A-Z]+)",/FixedString1 \1 FixedString2 \1/' file
FixedString1 A FixedString2 A
FixedString1 B FixedString2 B
FixedString1 C FixedString2 C
```

- With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk -F'"' '{print "FixedString1 " $2 " FixedString2 " $2}' file
FixedString1 A FixedString2 A
FixedString1 B FixedString2 B
FixedString1 C FixedString2 C
```

- with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
$ perl -F'"' -nE 'say "FixedString1 $F[1] FixedString2 $F[1]"' file
FixedString1 A FixedString2 A
FixedString1 B FixedString2 B
FixedString1 C FixedString2 C
```

- with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
while IFS='"' read -r _ x _; do echo "FixedString1 $x FixedString2 $x"; done < file
FixedString1 A FixedString2 A
FixedString1 B FixedString2 B
FixedString1 C FixedString2 C
```